# How can I maximise light in a small, space with minimal visual appearance of apparatus?

Tags: visible-light

I really looking for advice about something I would like to make and methods of gathering/collecting natural light and maximising it's potential in a small enclosed space...
My reference it the Stanhope lens...
I'm hoping to make a large 'way finder'(human scale) which I would like to have 'peep-holes' with hidden images inside, just like a big version of stanhope viewers...
With an enclosed external space containing a scene or model, it there a way I could direct the natural light into a small enclosed space and 'maximise' it for some atmospheric, internal illumination?
I hope that makes sense - I know I can use mirrors, but I wondered if there is a secret to using a particular lens or material which would direct the light and make the most of what is available without using electricity.
Thanks and apologies for being from a creative background! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gather light using a reflective parabolic dish, reflect its focus into a concave lens and add a bubbled glass in front of the lens. The light coming off the glass will be smeared out far and wide in your contraption. This should work great, but if you want to take it a step further, place a suitable variant of a disco ball at the center of your enclosure to further ensure the entire enclosure gets a fair share of ambient light.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you for your time - that's prefect! :)